# Tableau - Filter Based on 1st Order

Tags: tableau-api

I have a quick question. I'm trying to grab user ids based on their 1st purchase and products selected:

```
ID       Purchased
123      NSABC
124      NSDE
125      NSABC
123      EDEF
```

The way you know it's a 1st order and products that I want is with "NSABC". Then, I want to grab all the following rows irrespective of their purchase as long as the ID match. So in this scenario, ID 123, 125 I want Tableau to show the following:

```
123      NSABC
125      NSABC
123      EDEF
```

However, the issue is that when trying to write a calculated field, I only get the first purchase. My calculated field is:

```
IF CONTAINS([Purchased], 'NSABC') THEN ID END
```

This parses out the other result:

```
123      EDEF
```

Is there a way to check the 1st occurrence to = "True" and then grab all subsequent actions? I'm guessing I need some kind of LOD or any other calculated field?

> The NS flag means new customer and the E is an existing and therefore
> it gets replaced. All other letters are just product codes that can
> potentially change if they want to buy something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this calculation

```
{ FIXED [ID] : sum(IF [PURCHASED] = 'NSABC' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)} > 0
```

and select all records with TRUE condition (filter).  See

[image]